# ROS Approximate time synchronizer not entering callback

Tags: callback, synchronization, ros

I have created an approximate time synchronizer to sync stereo camera images are GPS. The time synchronizer does not enter the callback. I have already tried playing around with slop and `queue_size` parameters.

```
class sorghum_gps:
          def __init__(self,arg1):
            self.bridge = CvBridge()
            self.image_sub0 = message_filters.Subscriber("/cam0/image_raw",Image) 
            self.image_sub1 = message_filters.Subscriber("/cam1/image_raw",Image)
            self.gps_sub = message_filters.Subscriber("/fix",NavSatFix)
            self.ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([self.image_sub0,self.image_sub1, self.gps_sub],5,1) 
            self.ts.registerCallback(self.callback0)

          def callback0(self,data1, data2, data3):
            try:
              cv_image0 = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data1, "bgr8")
              cv_image1 = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data2, "bgr8")
              print('got_data')
            except CvBridgeError as e:
              print(e)

          def call1(self, data):
            print(data)

        def main(args):
         print(args[1], 'RUNNING')
         rospy.init_node('node_gps',anonymous=True)
         gp = sorghum_gps(args)
         try:
            rospy.spin()
         except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Shutting down")
         cv2.destroyAllWindows()


        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main(sys.argv)
```

Here are the details of the bag file I am trying to sync

> types:       sensor_msgs/Image     [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
>                sensor_msgs/NavSatFix [2d3a8cd499b9b4a0249fb98fd05cfa48] topics:      /fix                    7748 msgs    :
>   sensor_msgs/NavSatFix
>                /cam0/image_raw   1942 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
>                /cam1/image_raw   1942 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image

Comment: I don't know if it's your indenting in SO, but is your `if __name__ == '__main__'` section outside of the class? Is it init'ing the class at all? Or do you have the main & if main sections not under the class, so they can run?

Comment: Try adding a `queue_size` to your subscribers, perhaps. And check the actual publish rate of your msgs: try increasing the time approximation significantly. You currently have (under [ApproximateTimeSynchronizer](https://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/python/#message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer)) a queue_size of 5, and a delay of 1 second, is your data within that 1 second? Or check, does your data have headers (That are being set correctly)? If not, you should set the option `allow_headerless` if nonexistent, or fix if existing.

Comment: I tried adding `queue_size` to all subscribers, increasing `slop = 20` and adding `allow_headless = True`. None of the solutions worked. I am able to approximate time sync the two images, but adding `/fix` just doesn't work.

Comment: Check that `/fix/` is actually publishing. When you run the bag file, you can [play it back step by step](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data#rosbag.2FTutorials.2FRecording_and_playing_back_data.Examining_and_playing_the_bag_file). Check the time stamps on a few messages, that should be all it takes. Make sure you're listening to the right topic. Use `rostopic` and investigate your bag file. This does work, so the problem is either an obvious hardcoded path issue, or an issue with you data.